# Gravity Forms + Post Fields + Divi Load From Library

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms

I have Gravity Forms installed and am seeking to allow front-end users to publish a post in a pre-made Divi Post Template.

So far I have created a new Form in Gravity forms using a field called 'Post Fields'. 'Post Fields' allows a frontend user to publish posts.

My question is there any way i can get the 'Post Field' to publish within a premade Divi template.

Comment: Can you make the theme you want to use the default?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the post field, "custom field"
2. Set the Custom Field Name to Existing
3. Select the Post Content Layout (There may be something different for Divi Layout
4. Set the default value to the layout you want to use (May need an ID or just the name, May require some trial and error)
5. Under apperance enter gf_hidden in the Custom CSS Class box.
6. Add the CSS class below to your Sytle.css file in the theme. Divi may have an area in the settings for custom CSS. Use that instead as it wont get erased by updates

   `.gf_hidden {display:none;}`
   Now you will have a hidden field that sets the layout. Sorry I can not provide more detail. Maybe someone else that works with divi themes can fill in the blanks.

Comment: Not sure about step 4.  How do I set the default value?

Comment: Sorry, its a box under the advanced tab. Literally says default value

Comment: Thanks for help.  Not exactly sure what to put in that section 'Default Value'

Comment: Honestly I am not ether, looking at the divi theme it seems like the layouts are a custom post meta. You might need to make a post and then look in the database to see what is set. You might also ask elegant themes directly for the required values to set a custom layout. When your in the post editor you could use the developer console to inspect the layout selector and see what the values are. Right click the dropdown for layout selection and click inspect element.

Comment: What if I change the theme to Twenty Seventeen or a theme you are familiar?  What would I put in that 'Default Value' section?  Thanks again.

Comment: I found the elegant themes shortcode using this link:https://github.com/kary4/divituts/wiki/How-to-copy-divi-page-builder-shortcodes   My question is where do I insert the shortcodes?

Comment: That has more to do with including in theme files. I think we may be confusing Post Layouts with Divi Builder pages. I think what your going to need to do is make a custom layout and use that shortcode to include builder parts. https://andorwp.com/custom-post-and-page-templates-in-wordpress/ You might need a devoloper if your not comfortable building theme files. This seems to be a good example of what you can do: https://divi.space/blog/custom-single-post-template-for-multiple-author-sites/